# How to expand SliverAppBar programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver

I have a SliverAppBar, which scrolls up to shrink and scrolls down to expand.

I want to expand SliverAppBar when I switch BottomNavigationBar.

Under the current situation, the state of SliverAppBar before switching is kept.

This is my code.
https://gist.github.com/ysknsn/d90a84a180e32de5b0691de874c65d55

Any advices are helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just do the same you did to the `TabController`...

Put it in a local variable:

```
  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _scrollController = ScrollController(keepScrollOffset: true);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then use it in your NestedScrollView`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(

        length: _tabController.length,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          key: PageStorageKey(widget.title),
          ...
```

Then update the position when you click:

```
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    _scrollController.jumpTo(0);
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      _tabController.index = index;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry,  I can't use `jumpTo(0)`
because using PageStorageKey to store scroll position.

Comment: @ysknsn This's awkward. I just used your code and made the changes I wrote up... I tested it and it made the desired effect (My code has the PageStorageKey as well). Are you receiving any error message?

Comment: Thank you for testing.

Sorry for the lack of explanation.
There was no error, but it is not able to hold the scroll position.

Scroll down the left tab to `Left: 100`, switch to the right tab, and switch to the left tab.
In this state, I want it to remain as `Left: 100`, but results in `Left: 0`.

Comment: So you'll need some refactoring in your code. You have only one ScrollView shared between the two tabs (The tabs are children of the scrollView). You will need to have one scroll for each tab. And a controller for each one.

Comment: When using NestedScrollView, it seems that you can not set ScrollController to child ScrollView.
Since this implementation seems difficult this time, I decided to give up.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Add a scroll controller to your 'Custom Scroll View'

```
ScrollController _scrollController;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
_scrollController = ScrollController();
return Scaffold(
body: CustomScrollView( shrinkWrap: true, controller: _scrollController,
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
slivers: <Widget>[
SliverAppBar(
pinned: false,
:
:
:
:
:
:
:
:
:
onPressed: () {// Scroll to top when on click => Expand 
_scrollController.animateTo(
_scrollController.position.minScrollExtent,
duration:Duration(milliseconds:1300),
curve: Curves.decelerate,);
 },

onPressed: () {// Scroll to bottom when on click => Collapse
scrollController.animateTo(
    scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1300),
    curve: Curves.decelerate,
  );
 },
```